# When upload file size is big $form->isValid() returns null

Tags: forms, symfony

I have made the file upload system according to this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

It works when file size is small (less than 2MB), but it doesn't when file size is big.

I have investigated and found that somehow $form->isValid() returns null, when fils size is big.

```
public function fileUploadAction(Request $request){
    $document = new UpDocs();       
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
     ->add('name')
     ->add('file')
     ->getForm();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());
        if ($form->isValid()) { // it returns null.
```

my entity has annotation about maxsize (maxSize="60000000") and it doesn't have validation.xml

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */

class UpDocs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;


    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="60000000")
     */
    private $file;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to increase the maximum upload file size in your php.ini ?

Like explained here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize